# Probability of A1 and A2 happening when B has occured

Tags: probability

I need to know whether I'm right or wrong.

I came up with an answer of $1/36$. I'm in need of insights towards simplification of this approach.

Question is:

$D_1$ and $D_2$ are separate dices. Hence independent I suppose.

Let $D_1 = 1, 2, \dots 6$, $D_2 = 1, 2, \dots, 6$, $A_1 =$ "$D_1 = 6$", $A_2 =$ "$D_2 = 6$", $B = (D_1 + D_2)$ is even.

So given this data, calculate $P\left(A_1\text{ and } A_2) \mid B\right)$; i.e, what is the probability of $A_1$ and $A_2$ happening when $B$ has occurred.

Comment: Are $D_1$ and $D_2$ independents?

Comment: They are since D1 and D2 are separate dices, just assume like that. I updated the text though.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I did something like probability of A1 and A2 and B happening over probability of B happening. That was giving me 1/36.

Comment: @sinbadh On the right side, in the numerator part, I was hoping it should be 1/6 * 1/6 * 1/4 and denominator should be 1/4. It may give us 1/36. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(A_1,A_2|B)=\frac{P(A_1,A_2,B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A_1,A_2)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A_1)P(A_2)}{P(B)}$$

But $P(A_1)=\frac{1}{6}=P(A_2)$ and $P(B)=1-P(B)=1-P(D_1\mbox{ and }D_2\mbox{ have different parity})=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Thus $P(A_1,A_2|B)=\dfrac{\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{18}$

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife yeah that's right. Hopefully it won't affect the answer though.

Comment: I thought P(B)  should be (1/2 * 1/2) + (1/2 * 1/2) = 1/2

Comment: Of course. It is equivalent

Comment: Yeah I know. Just wanted to sound right. You know I was writing it 1/36 when it should have been 1/18. No words to describe this.

Comment: I initially thought it to be P(A1) * P(A2) * P(B) over P(B)  ie 1/6 * 1/6 * 1/2  /  1/2  =  1/36.

Comment: No. That is incorrect, cause $B$ is not independent of $A_1$ and $A_2$. Thus $P(A_1,A_2,B)\neq P(A_1)P(A_2)P(B)$

Comment: It would be 1/6 * 1/6 * 1 probably? Because B is becoming even because of A1 and A2 being 6? I got the part it isn't independent but since we're skipping the B part I also had a thought it might be because probability at max can be 1 and B is happening to be 1 because of A1 and A2.

Comment: The reason is that $A_1\cap A_2\subseteq B$. Then $A_1\cap A_2\cap B=A_1\cap A_2$

Answer (score 0):

How many ways can B occur? If $D_1, D_2$ are both even which can happen in $3^2$ ways or they are both odd which can happen in the same number of ways. So
$P(B)={2\cdot 3^2\over 6^2}={1\over2}$ which makes sense since the sum is even half the time. $P(A_1\cap A_2|B)=P(A_1\cap A_2\cap B)/P(B)={1\over6^2}/{1\over2}={1\over18}$.